# Как прокинуть Android-телефон через RDP?

Tags: android, android-studio, rdp

Есть удаленный рабочий стол (подключение через RDP).
Есть домашний комп. Есть Android-устройство.

Как можно прокинуть телефон, чтобы на удаленке подключить его к Android-Studio?

Флешки, диски и тд получается прокинуть.
Но когда выбираю телефон ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я знаю решение только для windows 7, на версиях выше не проверял.
Нужно поправить групповую политику локального компьютера через `gpedit.msc`

Далее входите:
`Конфигурация компьютера`  -> `Административные шаблоны`  -> `Компоненты Windows` -> `Службы удаленных рабочих столов` -> `Клиент подключения к удаленному рабочему столу` -> `Перенаправление USB-устройств RemoteFX` -> `Разрешить перенаправление RDP для других поддерживаемых USB-устройств RemoteFX с этого компьютера`

Включаете и выбираете нужную настройку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: большое спасибо. в win10 надо еще кое-что добавить, но вы толкнули в абсолютно нужно направлении!))

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо Andrey Mihalev за ответ!
для win10 и win11 надо сделать еще доп шаг.
Полный гайд:

Следующие действия надо выполнить на обоих компьютерах: который подключается к удаленному, и на самом удаленном.

1. Открываем «Редактор локальной групповой политики».
2. Переходим в
   •   Конфигурация Компьютера
   •   Административные Шаблоны
   •   Компоненты Windows
   •   Службы удаленных рабочих столов
   •   Узел сеансов удаленных рабочих столов
   •   Перенаправление устройств и ресурсов
   •   Не разрешать перенаправление поддерживаемых самонастраиваемых устройств
   •   Выбираем «отключить»
3. Возвращаемся к
   •   Службы удаленных рабочих столов
   •   Клиент подключения к удаленному рабочему столу
   •   Перенаправление USB-устройств RemoteX
   •   Разрешает RDP-перенаправление других поддерживаемых USB-устройств RemoteFX с данного компьютера.
   •   Выбираем «включено»
   •   Указываем «Администраторы и пользователи»
4. Открываем командную строку от имени администратора и выполняем команду:
   **gpupdate /force**
5. Перезагружаем компьютера.